# no such table Error inserting SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Here is my logs:

> 08-10 23:11:01.644    2341-2341/com.projects.learnwords.app E/Database﹕ Error inserting            > CORRECT_ENGLISH_WORDS=0 SECOND_WORD=собака CORRECT_RUSSIANS_WORDS=0 FIRST_WORD=dog
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: vv: , while compiling: INSERT INTO 
>   vv(CORRECT_ENGLISH_WORDS, SECOND_WORD, CORRECT_RUSSIANS_WORDS, FIRST_WORD) VALUES(?, ?, ?,  > ?);

my db class:

```
public class DbControl {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "LearnWordsDB.db";
    private final String TABLE_NAME;
    private final int DB_VERSION;

    static final String FIRST_WORD = "FIRST_WORD";
    static final String SECOND_WORD = "SECOND_WORD";
    static final String CORRECT_FIRST_WORDS = "CORRECT_ENGLISH_WORDS";
    static final String CORRECT_SECOND_WORDS = "CORRECT_RUSSIANS_WORDS";

    private Cursor cursor;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper;
    private Context context;

public DbControl(Context context, final String TABLE_NAME, int DB_VERSION){
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME;
    this.DB_VERSION =DB_VERSION;
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    dbOpenHelper = new DbOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    database = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close(){
    dbOpenHelper.close();
}

public void insert(final String FIRST_WORD, final String SECOND_WORD,
                   final int CORRECT_FIRST_WORDS, final int CORRECT_SECOND_WORDS) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(Dictionary.FIRST_WORD, FIRST_WORD);
    values.put(Dictionary.SECOND_WORD, SECOND_WORD);
    values.put(Dictionary.CORRECT_FIRST_WORDS, CORRECT_FIRST_WORDS);
    values.put(Dictionary.CORRECT_SECOND_WORDS, CORRECT_SECOND_WORDS);

    database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}

private class DbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbOpenHelper(Context context, final String DB_NAME, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + FIRST_WORD + " TEXT, " +
                SECOND_WORD + " TEXT, " + CORRECT_FIRST_WORDS + " INTEGER, " + CORRECT_SECOND_WORDS + " INTEGER )";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
        db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
  }
}
```

Here I tried to insert:

```
private void writeToDictionary(String contents, String dictName){

    DbControl dict = new DbControl(getApplicationContext(), dictName, 1);
    DictionaryRow[] dictRows = parseWords(contents);
    try {
        dict.open();
        for(DictionaryRow dr: dictRows) {
                dict.insert(dr.getFirstWord(), dr.getSecondWord(), dr.getCorrectFirstWords(), dr.getCorrectSecondWords());
        }
    } catch (SQLException e)
    {
        Log.e("CREATE_OR_OPEN_ERROR", e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

My phone API level 10.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Create the table (`vv`) and/or use the correct table name. The error message says what the problem is: don't doubt it.

Comment: I think the table is creating when I call getWritableDatabase() method isn't it?

Comment: No, not always; only if the database didn't exist yet when you tried to open it, meaning it's being created for the first time. I think the issue is you take a TABLE_NAME as a parameter to the constructor, expecting it to create this new table when opening an existing database, and this will not work. You should initialize ALL the tables you need in `onCreate` as it only happens once per database. Given than, I don't think you should have that constructor parameter and I don't think you should create a new instance of `DbHelper` on every call to `open()`.

Comment: When you use the DbHelper it might, but your code looks incomplete. I don't even see "vv" in the insert, much less the onCreate

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is you take a TABLE_NAME as a parameter to the constructor, expecting it to create this new table when opening an existing database, and this will not work. You should initialize ALL the tables you need in `onCreate` as it only happens once per database.

Given that, I don't think you should have that constructor parameter and I don't think you should create a new instance of `DbHelper` on every call to `open()`. I would probably go further than that and make `DbControl` a singleton, which just wraps the `DbHelper` and exposes the methods you create.